# Module 'tensorflow.tools.docs.doc_controls' has no attribute 'inheritable_header'

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-estimator

Running estimator from tensorflow today and came up with this error, any idea how to solve it?

```
File "C:\Users\ASUS Laptop\anaconda3\envs\tf_gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_estimator\python\estimator\estimator.py", line 70, in <module>
    @doc_controls.inheritable_header("""\
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.tools.docs.doc_controls' has no attribute 'inheritable_header'
```

This is in my estimator.py file:
@doc_controls.inheritable_header("""
Warning: Estimators are not recommended for new code.  Estimators run
`v1.Session`-style code which is more difficult to write correctly, and
can behave unexpectedly, especially when combined with TF 2 code. Estimators
do fall under our
[compatibility guarantees](https://tensorflow.org/guide/versions), but will
receive no fixes other than security vulnerabilities. See the
[migration guide](https://tensorflow.org/guide/migrate) for details.
""")

Answer (score 10):

Check your `tensorflow-estimator` version, it seems that version 2.7 from the 30 of October not compatible with some libraries.

try version 2.6:

```
pip install --upgrade tensorflow-estimator==2.6.0
```

EDIT:-
Also downgrade keras to version 2.6.0:

```
pip install --upgrade keras==2.6.0
```

Comment: This gave me an ```AlreadyExistsError: Another metric with the same name already exists.```

Comment: To be a little more specific here, `tensorflow-estimator==2.7.0` uses a decorator from `tensorflow` that is not introduced until `tensorflow==2.7.0`. `tensorflow==2.6.0` (and presumably all `2.6.x` versions), unfortunately, only pins `tensorflow-estimator~=2.6`, which leaves `tfe==2.7.0` to be pulled in. And `tfe` does not have `tensorflow` as an explicit dependency of its own, causing the breakdown of semantic versioning we see here.

Comment: Pranav's edit accounts for the aforementioned `AlreadyExistsError`.

Comment: By the way, tensorflow 2.6.2 is released which correctly sets upper limit on tensorflow-estimator version, which fixes these problems.

Answer (score 1):

Either upgrade or downgrade tensorflow-estimator package to match tensorflow version.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).